# Angular 2 - MockBackend - Passtrough equivalent?

Tags: angular, mocking, backend

I need to dynamically enable some backend "live mocking" in my Angular 2 application for some specific url in some dynamic conditions (this is not unit testing !).

In angular 1, I used to enable mocking using regular expression and let other requests "pass through" using the method of the same name.

But in angular 2, I'm stuck with the following code :

```
this.backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
   // ...
  if ( regexp.test(c.request.url) && c.request.method === 0) {
      c.mockRespond(...);
  } else {
     // WHERE IS MY c.passThrough() method ????
  }
});
```

Is there a way to tell the mock backend to play the "real" calls in some situations ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is by including the real XHRBackend as a dependency to your fake backend provider, then using the real backend to perform an http request to the server for any unmocked URLs like this:

```
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
    // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions, realBackend: XHRBackend) => {
        // array in local storage for registered users
        let users: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

        // configure fake backend
        backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
            // wrap in timeout to simulate server api call
            setTimeout(() => {

                // mocked urls handled here ...

                // pass through any requests not handled above
                let realHttp = new Http(realBackend, options);
                realHttp.get(connection.request.url).subscribe((response: Response) => { connection.mockRespond(response); });

            }, 500);

        });

        return new Http(backend, options);
    },
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, XHRBackend]
};
```

See [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/11/24/angular-2-mockbackend-example-for-backendless-development) for more details and demo